# problem on installing Android Studio and React-Native CLI

Tags: react-native, android-studio, path

I've followed the installation instructions for ReactNative on the official site but can't get my project to build and install on any device. The issue seems to be that React Native can't seem to locate my Android SDK.

```
PS E:\grid\cli\AwesomeProject> npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the Android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0
```

Otherwise, I installed Android SDK 33.0.0 and ANDROID SDK COMMAND-LINE tools

[image]

[image]

I also set up environment variables correctly, but it doesn't recognise Android SDK for building...
What is the problem?

I uninstalled ANDROID SDK COMMAND-LINE tools and installed it manually, but It didn't get any results removed all paths and environment variables and then set them up again correctly

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> React Native can't seem to locate my Android SDK.

Actually, React Native shouldn't do that. The `Android SDK` installing procedure should introduce it to the PATH of the operating system. By the way, now you must add the `Android SDK` address to the PATH of the OS. Follow the below steps:

1. It's obvious your OS is Windows, so right-click on the My Computer.
2. After choosing properties, a window will be appeared, then click on the Advanced tab and then choose Environment variables.
3. Edit the PATH on the system variables window by highlighting and getting the edit click.
4. In the Edit System Variables window, insert the cursor at the end of the Variable Value field.
5. If the last character is not a semi-colon (;), add one.
6. After the last semicolon, type the full path of the file you want to find.

   ```
   C:\Users\vomino\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   ```
7. Click OK in each open window
8. Restart System

Now it should works.